# Pycharm Python tkinter Code hinting for ttk options

Tags: python, tkinter, ide, pycharm, ttk

so I realized in pycharm there is no code hinting for ttk object options. Does any one know of a plugin or settings in pycharm that will provide code hinting for tkinter object options?

If not do you know of an IDE that does this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/home/index.php) with [Pydev](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/eclipsepython.html) does the job well.

Comment: I'm ready to except your answer. I just need you to verify one thing, does Eclipse with Pydev have code hinting for ttk options?

Comment: @Mark Yes it does. Anything you import has hints.